# Doing this with a for cycle

Tags: java, android

And now a very easy java question....

```
        Object[] objectList={
            new Object(name[0], description[0], R.drawable.creep_0),
            new Object(name[1], description[1], R.drawable.creep_1),
            new Object(name[2], description[2], R.drawable.creep_2),
            new Object(name[3], description[3], R.drawable.creep_3),
};
```

How can i do this dynamically with a `for` cycle? Thanks!

Comment: It's called a for *loop*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Creep[] creeps = new Creep[] 
    { R.drawable.creep_0, R.drawable.creep_1, R.drawable.creep_2, 
      R.drawable.creep_3 };
Object[] objectList = new Object[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    objectList[i] = new Object(name[i], description[i], creeps[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! But is there a way to write the creeps part inside the for cycle? i mean something like R.drawable.creep_i

Comment: @Abramodj: Not as straightforward as `R.drawable.creep_i`. You have to use reflection to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList objectList = new ArrayList(); 
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
     Object o = new Object(name[i], description[i], R.drawable.creep_i);
     objectList.Add(o);
}
```

Comment: R.drawable.creep_i will not work as this will refer to a (presumably) non existent field of R.